# UPDATE with CASE Statements using a similar foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a database that tracks a household. It keeps the household head as a client in a separate table, but uses their ID as a foreign key in the household table. I need to be able to add multiple people in a household. I tried using just an UPDATE statement, but it only replaced the data when I tried to add multiple people at once. I am trying to do this not using DELETE and INSERT statements for fear of losing information. For added information, this is all manipulated by a PHP Fat-Free Website because my school teaches it.

```
function editHousehold($id, $name, $age, $gender){
    $id = $this->getLastId();

    $sql= "UPDATE Household SET `name`=:name, age=:age, gender=:gender WHERE 
           Guests_ClientId=:Guests_ClientId";
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':Guests_ClientId', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Vs.

```
function editNeeds($id,$resource,$date, $amount, $voucher, $checkNum){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Needs WHERE Guests_ClientId = $id";
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $id = $this->getLastId();
    $sql= "INSERT INTO Needs (resource, visitDate, amount, voucher, checkNum, Guests_ClientId)
            VALUES (:resource, :date , :amount, :voucher, :checkNum, $id)";
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':resource', $resource, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':amount', $amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':voucher', $voucher, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':checkNum', $checkNum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
}
/**
 * edit households, removes the old and replaces witha new set of values
 * @param $id
 * @param $name
 * @param $age
 * @param $gender
 */
function editHousehold($id, $name, $age, $gender){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Household  WHERE Guests_ClientId = $id";
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $id = $this->getLastId();
    $sql= "INSERT INTO Household (name, age, gender,Guests_ClientId)
            VALUES (:name,:age,:gender,$id)";
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Comment: Please share sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hello RyGuy8806, welcome to Stack Overflow. You would need to provide sample data and expected results for both tables (as tabular text, not images) -  otherwise your question is not likely to receive helpful answers.

Comment: As noted by others, you will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: You cannot loose data using an INSERT statement when you use transactions and ensure that all errors are handled correctly. Otherwise, I agree with other commenters that you out to provide a sample create table statement along with sample data.

Comment: Are you looking for an upsert? Mysql has `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL, When I try and add a new member to my database, I lose anyone who was connected to the main client in the first place. I have another function that practically does the same thing with the same issue.

Comment: To further my explanation, I did try CASE and IF() statements,but it didn't help. I did read that the IF statement isn't always supported and it depends on what version of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for an "either insert new entry or update if the primary key exists" type of statement. This is called "upsert", and MySQL provides it in the form of [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

It will insert new entries, *unless* the primary key of one of the entries to insert already exists. If so, it will instead update the existing entry.

Comment: If it fixes your issue, come back once you can mark an answer as accepted and do so, please, in case somebody else has the same problem. If it doesn't, let me know.

Comment: This answer didn't work, but I now know why the DELETE & INSERT was used in the first place. The foreign key was being preserved this way.

Thank you for all your help.